# loop over column and average elements at fixed interval

Tags: python, loops, pandas-groupby, mean, intervals

I am completely stuck. In my original dataframe I have 1 column of interest (fluorescence) and I want to take a fixed amount of elements (=3, color yellow) at fixed interval (5) and average them. The output should be saved into a NewList.

```
fluorescence = df.iloc[1:20, 0]
fluorescence=pd.to_numeric(fluorescence)
## add a list to count
fluorescence['time']= list(range(1,20,1))
## create a list with interval
interval = list(range(1, 20, 5))
NewList=[]

for i in range(len(fluorescence)):
  if fluorescence['time'][i] == interval[i]:
   NewList.append(fluorescence[fluorescence.tail(3).mean()])

print(NewList)
```

[image]

Any input is welcome!!
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I'm taking subset of dataframe for every 5 consecutive iterations and taking tail 3 rows mean

```
import pandas as pd    
fluorescence=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])    


NewList=[]    
j=0    
for i1 in range(4,len(fluorescence),5):    
    NewList.append(fluorescence.loc[j:i1,0].tail(3).mean())    
    j=i1    

print(NewList)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of data and you want to grab 3 entries out of every 5 you can segment your list as follows:

```
from statistics import mean
data = [63, 64, 43, 91, 44, 84, 14, 43, 87, 53, 81, 98, 34, 33, 60, 82, 86, 6, 81, 96, 99, 10, 76, 73, 63, 89, 70, 29, 32, 3, 98, 52, 37, 8, 2, 80, 50, 99, 71, 5, 7, 35, 56, 47, 40, 2, 8, 56, 69, 15, 76, 52, 24, 56, 89, 52, 30, 70, 68, 71, 17, 4, 39, 39, 85, 29, 18, 71, 92, 8, 1, 95, 52, 94, 71, 88, 59, 64, 100, 96, 65, 15, 89, 19, 63, 38, 50, 65, 52, 26, 46, 79, 85, 32, 12, 67, 35, 22, 54, 81]
new_data = []
for i in range(0, len(data), 5):
    every_five = data[i:i+5]
    three_out_of_five = every_five[2:5]
    new_data.append(mean(three_out_of_five))
print(new_data)
```

Comment: thank you very much! The code no works and I understand it!

Comment: @MartinaLazzarin With pleasure!